# Get properties from different scripts in game engine?

Tags: python, game-engine

The question explains itself. I have a property in one script and another property in another script. I am not sure how to define the python scripts in the blender game engine. How can I get a property from a different script in the game engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties belong to game objects rather than Python code.

You write a property with `myGameObject[propertyName] = value`

example:

```
hitObject = sensor.hitObject
hitObject["detected"] = True
```

You read a property with `value = myGameObject[propertyName]`.

example:

```
hitObject = sensor.hitObject
wasAlreadyDetected = hitObject["detected"]
```

I hope it helps

Comment: So, if properties belong to game objects, when would I use properties in python code? Also, thanks for the answer! ;)

Comment: I may misunderstand you, but you use properties when you want to store data at a specific object. Your python code lives as long as the code gets executed. That means all variables will die after exiting the python controllers execution. When you store values in a property you can access it from a different Python controller execution either from same or from other object.